# Using bookmark button in UISearchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

How can we use the bookmark button that appears in UISearchbar? I didn't find any delegate methods for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = YES;
```

And then you can use the delegate method for when it is clicked:

```
- (void)searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```